# What Oracle data type is easily converted to BIT in MSSQL via SSIS?

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a Data Flow from an Oracle table to an MSSQL table with one field of data type BIT. The Oracle table is using the characters Y and N at the moment (I'm unsure of the data type and have no way of checking), but the MSSQL table needs to be data type BIT. What type of cast can I use on the Oracle query so that the data is pulled smoothly over?

Comment: I assume you can connect to Oracle to extract the data, in which case you should be able to query the schema metadata (e.g. `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS`) to check the data type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use char(1) and then use a derived column transformation like this:

```
(DT_BOOL)(OracleField == "Y"?1:0)
```

Give this column a name like OracleFieldAsBool
and then use it instead of the original column in the rest of your data flow.